# Load XML Data Into SQL Table (Azure) via Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: xml, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, sqlxml

I am trying to load XML Data into Azure Table using ADF V2. There is a connector for XML as a Source but for some reason I am not able to get the data loaded as requirement.

[image]
[image]

So I tried to load the Entire XML into a stage table Column (XML TYPE) so that I can use XQuery to get the desired Result but unable to.

Any Ideas to load and query data by any other means using Azure Stack?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to what is the error which you were , but i did uploaded the below dummy XML data on to SQL .

XML dummy

```
<note>
<record>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</record>
<record>
<to>Tove1</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</record>
<record>
<to>Tove2</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</record>
</note>
```

This is my output .

[image]

Please make sure is done correctly , this is the thing which worked for me .
[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions .

Thanks
Himanshu

Comment: Himanshu.  Try with the XML that I have shared.  The one that you have shared is pretty straightforward to use in ADF.